# Spring boot application give this error: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' but when i login with console everything works fine

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot

```
.   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.1.0.RELEASE)
```

> 2019-04-20 16:26:02.328  INFO 8156 --- [           main] c.d.learning.ShoppingcartApplication     : Starting ShoppingcartApplication on Divyas-MacBook-Air.local with PID 8156 (/Users/divya/Divya/workspace-sts-3.9.6.RELEASE/shoppingcart/target/classes started by divya in /Users/divya/Divya/workspace-sts-3.9.6.RELEASE/shoppingcart)
>   2019-04-20 16:26:02.332  INFO 8156 --- [           main] c.d.learning.ShoppingcartApplication     : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
>   2019-04-20 16:26:02.987  INFO 8156 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data repositories in DEFAULT mode.
>   2019-04-20 16:26:03.009  INFO 8156 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 15ms. Found 0 repository interfaces.
>   2019-04-20 16:26:03.498  INFO 8156 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$5fa72150] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
>   2019-04-20 16:26:03.807  INFO 8156 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
>   2019-04-20 16:26:03.826  INFO 8156 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
>   2019-04-20 16:26:03.826  INFO 8156 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/9.0.12
>   2019-04-20 16:26:03.835  INFO 8156 --- [           main] o.a.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener   : The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: [/Users/divya/Library/Java/Extensions:/Library/Java/Extensions:/Network/Library/Java/Extensions:/System/Library/Java/Extensions:/usr/lib/java:.]
>   2019-04-20 16:26:03.978  INFO 8156 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
>   2019-04-20 16:26:03.978  INFO 8156 --- [           main] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1588 ms
>   2019-04-20 16:26:04.022  INFO 8156 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
>   2019-04-20 16:26:04.022  INFO 8156 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
>   2019-04-20 16:26:04.022  INFO 8156 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'formContentFilter' to: [/*]
>   2019-04-20 16:26:04.022  INFO 8156 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
>   2019-04-20 16:26:04.023  INFO 8156 --- [           main] .s.DelegatingFilterProxyRegistrationBean : Mapping filter: 'springSecurityFilterChain' to: [/*]
>   2019-04-20 16:26:04.023  INFO 8156 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Servlet dispatcherServlet mapped to [/]

### getDataSource: org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource@1e6308a9

> 2019-04-20 16:26:04.337  INFO 8156 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.3.7.Final}
>   2019-04-20 16:26:04.339  INFO 8156 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
>   2019-04-20 16:26:16.638  INFO 8156 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.4.Final}
>   2019-04-20 16:26:17.157  WARN 8156 --- [           main] o.h.e.j.e.i.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator     : HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata : Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
>   2019-04-20 16:26:17.170  INFO 8156 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
>   2019-04-20 16:26:17.186  INFO 8156 --- [           main] o.h.e.j.e.i.LobCreatorBuilderImpl        : HHH000422: Disabling contextual LOB creation as connection was null

### getSessionFactory: org.hibernate.internal.SessinFactoryImpl@31d45c55

> 2019-04-20 16:26:18.564  INFO 8156 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
>   2019-04-20 16:26:18.811  INFO 8156 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.w.s.WelcomePageHandlerMapping    : Adding welcome page template: index
>   2019-04-20 16:26:19.378  INFO 8156 --- [           main] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Creating filter chain: any request, [org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@77098877, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@7775dca5, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@352df57e, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@47529ae7, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter@5ed66b0, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@46bea4ca, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@508da476, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@6d83221, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@618c59f5, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@95c5d95, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@6e0214de]
>   2019-04-20 16:26:19.646  INFO 8156 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
>   2019-04-20 16:26:19.655  INFO 8156 --- [           main] c.d.learning.ShoppingcartApplication     : Started ShoppingcartApplication in 32.774 seconds (JVM running for 38.572)

Comment: Voting as off-topic:  unclear what you're asking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> rg.hibernate.cfg.Environment : HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found 2019-04-20 16:26:16.638 INFO 8156 --- [ main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.4.Final} 2019-04-20 16:26:17.157 WARN 8156 --- [ main] o.h.e.j.e.i.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator : HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata : Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Seems you have not defined properties for database connection. Add those properties into `application.properties`

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://mysqlhost:port/<schema_name>
spring.datasource.username=<username>
spring.datasource.password=<password>
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
spring.jpa.show-sql = false
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings=false
```

Comment: Please fond my application.properties spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/shoppingcart
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=mysql 
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver 
spring.mvc.dispatch-options-request=true 
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.current_session_context_class=org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.SpringSessionContexts

Comment: java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) .    when i login with mysql -u root -p mysql im able to login but by spring boot application im facing this issue

Comment: can you post entire project in github? I would like to have a look.

Comment: problem is with your password.. You have added space after _mysql _. Remove space and try

Answer (score 0):

you need to deinfe the `spring.datasource.url` in your application.properties which you have not defined in that. 
it is something like
`spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/<database_name>`